# NÃO mostrar alert messeger ao recarregar a página

Tags: php, javascript

Estou criando uma página de controle para meu site, mas quando a página é recarregada sempre aparece um alert perguntando se eu gostaria de reenviar parâmetros usados. Gostaria de saber como faço para retirar este alert ou enviar sua confirmação automaticamente.

Comment: Olá Larissa. Bem vinda ao SOpt. Somente com esses dados não é possível lhe ajudar. Será que poderia postar o código fonte de seu site? Pelo menos a parte do javascript. Provavelmente tem algum alert no load da página. Aproveitando, aconselho a fazer um [tour] em nosso site para ver como funcionar. E, sempre que possível, poste um [mcve] do seu problema. Desta forma fica muito mais fácil de ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi o que esta acontecendo é que você usou um formulário com o method post e para a pagina na qual foi enviada tenta recarrega-la, se o que entendi esta correto isso é uma ação do browser pois no HTTP headers que ele vai enviar para o servidor é um header com method post e ele reconfirma o envio dos mesmos dados usados anteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não sei como você está realizando esse recarregamento, mas se for automático pelo sistema, envie via get passando url, eu tive esse problema com o usuário dando F5 pra recarregar a página, para solucionar validei se o post for igual ao anterior ele retorna a página via url:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $request = implode($_POST);
   if(isset($_SESSION['last_request']) && ($_SESSION['last_request'] == $request)) {
      header("Location:".$url); 
      exit;
   }else {
      $_SESSION['last_request'] = $request;
   }
}
```